# Is Ruby on Rails appropriate for what I am trying to achieve? Creating CRUD scaffolds for existing MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, crud

I have previously created localhost-only RoR applications where models were created manually with scaffolds generated for them, creating a nice, quick, easy to use CRUD interface for the data. I did this in Netbeans using SQLite.

Now I have a server with a MySQL database and wish to create a quick CRUD application which provides a quick and easy way to view data in the database and give a few options like edit/delete. As my database is already specified by MySQL this seems to open up a massive can of worms, making this a lot less straight forward in comparison to my Netbeans venture into scaffold-generated crud web apps in RoR.

I have looked into dumping the schema of my current database, db:raking it, then generating the scaffolds. Is this the correct approach? I have also read about Magic Model Generator. Is this the best way to go about getting the MySQL database to a RoR model format? http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_model_generator/

I guess what I'm asking is, for my database structure, is RoR appropriate to mock-up a quick CRUD web app so that the data can have basic manipulation performed on it?

Below is the schema.rb for my MySQL database. There is a FK relationship on userId and attachmentId.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 0) do

  create_table "attachments", :primary_key => "attachmentId", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "attachmentName",               :null => false
    t.string "fileType",       :limit => 30, :null => false
    t.binary "content",                      :null => false
    t.string "printCode"
  end

  create_table "emails", :primary_key => "emailId", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "userId",       :limit => 11,   :null => false
    t.integer "attachmentId", :limit => 11,   :null => false
    t.string  "body",         :limit => 1000
    t.string  "subject"
  end

  add_index "emails", ["attachmentId"], :name => "attachmentId", :unique => true
  add_index "emails", ["userId"], :name => "userId"

  create_table "printUsers", :primary_key => "userId", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "email", :null => false
  end

  add_index "printUsers", ["email"], :name => "email", :unique => true

end
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. If the db already exists, why do you want to create it again? Just create active record models and specify their relationships. The specific fields will be automatically figured out by each Active record model using the AR reflection features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be several approaches to using rails with an existing database. See [Connect rails to existing postgres DB - models not seen by console and controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297972/connect-rails-to-existing-postgres-db-models-not-seen-by-console-and-controlle), and especially the links from it: http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_model_generator/ and http://blog.aizatto.com/2007/05/21/activerecord-without-rails/

It's good to point out that you don't need to use ActiveRecord with rails. Your model can be any Object, so it might be easier to use something like [sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) or [arel](https://github.com/nkallen/arel) to access the data.

Another approach would be to migrate the data out of your existing database and into a new one that you generate by scaffolding your models.

Comment: Alright, so I've got my application created by doing `rails test -d mysql`. I've also edited my `database.yml` file to contain the link to my MySQL database. So I now want to create the models and copy all their associations from the database into the models using the magic model generator? From that I should be able to make scaffolds, correct?

Comment: It looks like that project hasn't been updated in a while ( https://github.com/drnic/magic_model_generator ) so I'm not sure how well it'll work in rails 3. Since you're breaking with convention, it's probably time to lose the scaffolding, and generate each component: tests (you start here, right?), routing, view, model, (you can skip db migrations if you're hooking it up manually), controller.

Comment: This is a good set of slides that show various methods of hooking up ActiveRecord to a legacy db: http://www.slideshare.net/napcs/rails-and-legacy-databases-railsconf-2009

Comment: I've given up on using RoR for this now. Thanks for your responses and I'm sure they're decent resources on getting this running so I'm marking your response as the answer.

Comment: The 'magic model generator' gem is Rails 2 only. For those finding this in the future, here is a much more comprehensive gem-solution for modern versions of rails which creates scaffold commands - https://github.com/frenesim/schema_to_scaffold